# Win32 GUI: sizing status bar in dialog-based app

Tags: user-interface, winapi

I have simple dialog-based application with a status bar:

```
InitCommonControls();
HWND hStatus = CreateWindowEx(...);
SendMessage(hStatus, SB_SETPARTS, ...);
```

I would like it to remain always at the bottom of the dialog, even if the dialog gets resized.

I tried `SendMessage(hStatus, WM_SIZE, 0, 0);` in `WM_SIZE` of the dialog procedure but it doesn't work (status bar stays at the same position). Do I have to move it manually?

Comment: Skip this question, it works... Sorry for the spam..

Comment: resizing on a WM_SIZE *notification* has to have been one of the most stupid descisions ever. oh well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works, I don't know what happened....